# Yii2 - Only one select get options

Tags: php, yii, yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-advanced-app

I got an issue. I have 3 select inputs, that i want to fill in with same options. First input gets options, but another two don't. I've tried everything. Last thing, that i tried was select 3 different queries and fill each one separately. Unfortunately, i get same issue.

Thanks for advices.

**Controller**

```
$dataPbxObj1 = Sipend::find()
        ->select('cc_sip_end.*')
        ->leftJoin('cc_reseller_to_pbx', '`cc_reseller_to_pbx`.`ID_PBX` = `cc_sip_end`.`id`')
        ->where(["in", "cc_reseller_to_pbx.id_cc_reseller", $reseller->id_cc_reseller])->all();

    $dataPbxObj2 = Sipend::find()
        ->select('cc_sip_end.*')
        ->leftJoin('cc_reseller_to_pbx', '`cc_reseller_to_pbx`.`ID_PBX` = `cc_sip_end`.`id`')
        ->where(["in", "cc_reseller_to_pbx.id_cc_reseller", $reseller->id_cc_reseller])->all();

    $dataPbxObj3 = Sipend::find()
        ->select('cc_sip_end.*')
        ->leftJoin('cc_reseller_to_pbx', '`cc_reseller_to_pbx`.`ID_PBX` = `cc_sip_end`.`id`')
        ->where(["in", "cc_reseller_to_pbx.id_cc_reseller", $reseller->id_cc_reseller])->all();

    $dataPbx1 = ArrayHelper::map($dataPbxObj1,'id','popis');
    $dataPbx2 = ArrayHelper::map($dataPbxObj2,'id','popis');
    $dataPbx3 = ArrayHelper::map($dataPbxObj3,'id','popis');
```

**View** (all this selects are same)

```
<?=$form->field($modelSip, 'ID_PBX')->widget(Select2::className(),
               ["data" => $dataPbx3,'hideSearch' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: HTML IDs need to have unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably needs to use unique IDs - by default Yii generates ID based on field name, but with 3 identical fields, IDs will be the same, and Select2 init will apply only for first of them.

```
<?=$form->field($modelSip, 'ID_PBX')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'options' => ['id' => 'ID_PBX1'],
    'data' => $dataPbx,
    'hideSearch' => true,
]) ?>

<?=$form->field($modelSip, 'ID_PBX')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'options' => ['id' => 'ID_PBX2'],
    'data' => $dataPbx,
    'hideSearch' => true,
]) ?>

<?=$form->field($modelSip, 'ID_PBX')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'options' => ['id' => 'ID_PBX3'],
    'data' => $dataPbx,
    'hideSearch' => true,
]) ?>
```

BTW: you don't need to query options list 3 times, you can do it once and use the same result in 3 fields.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but i've got same issue. First select contains options, but another two don't.